# Issue with button text shifting

Tags: android, layout

I'm having this odd issue. I have these buttons where the button's text is shifted downward upon certain actions. For example, I have a spinner with choices and one of the choices makes some buttons invisible while others are made visible. When I choose these, the buttons made visible all have their text shifted downward. Nothing else is shifted, just the text on the buttons. I've tried this on 1.5 and it works fine, no text is shifted, but I have issues with 2.1 and I really cannot figure it out. Any ideas or help would be great. Thanks.

Here is the xml of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<TableLayout android:id="@+id/testpracHeader" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <!-- android:background="#ff0000"-->

    <TableRow>
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/testprac_menu" 
            android:layout_width="200px" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>
        <View android:id="@+id/header_space_buffer" 
            android:layout_width="40px" 
            android:layout_height="30px"
            android:gravity="center"></View>
        <Button android:text="New" 
            android:id="@+id/newInterval" 
            android:layout_width="80px" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/bottomStruct" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:layout_width="80px" 
            android:text="Replay" 
            android:id="@+id/replay" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/playInterval" 
            android:text="Play"
            android:layout_width="160px" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Submit" 
            android:id="@+id/submit" 
            android:layout_width="80px" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i use the `testprac` spinner, the replay, new and submit buttons go invisible and the play button becomes visible (which is what I want). This seems to be when the issue seems to start. The play button's text is completely gone (probably shifted to low to see) and when I go back to the other button's are visible I get the issue that is shown below. The left is the issue before using the spinner, and the right is the issue. I don't know if it is just the spinner that causes this.

[image: The GUI before I invoke the spinner]
[image: The GUI after I invoke the spinner]

Comment: You need to post the suspect XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a bug when using `Spinner`s inside `RelativeLayout`. If you try to change your root layout to a `LinearLayout` you2ll see it works as expected.

Changes on your original layout:

1. root layout changed to LinearLayout.
2. a dummy view added between `TableLayout`s to seperate them top and
   bottom.

**Note:** I found your question while trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763794/android-button-looses-its-text-alignment/19765740#19765740). Seems similar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<TableLayout android:id="@+id/testpracHeader" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- android:background="#ff0000"-->

    <TableRow>
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/testprac_menu" 
            android:layout_width="200px" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>
        <View android:id="@+id/header_space_buffer" 
            android:layout_width="40px" 
            android:layout_height="30px"
            android:gravity="center"></View>
        <Button android:text="New" 
            android:id="@+id/newInterval" 
            android:layout_width="80px" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<View  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/bottomStruct" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:layout_width="80px" 
            android:text="Replay" 
            android:id="@+id/replay" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/playInterval" 
            android:text="Play"
            android:layout_width="160px" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Submit" 
            android:id="@+id/submit" 
            android:layout_width="80px" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text is shifted *inside* the button? Could be a bug. Have you tried it on Android 2.2?

Comment: Yeah it shifted inside the button. The button's placement and everything else is still fine. I'll have to try it on 2.2. I'll see if I can provide a photo.

Comment: Is setVisibility () the only method that you call in relation to these buttons? Have you tried with View.GONE instead of View.INVISIBLE? Is this orientation dependent?

Comment: The View.GONE is not exactly what I want. Although, I did move the buttons a lot higher (than what is shown in the picture) and they did not have that issue anymore. Could the issue be because of a bug with the command android:layout_alignParentBottom?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the android:layout_width="fill_parent". I changed this to android:layout_width="wrap_content" and it worked fine. I don't know really why "fill_parent" was an issue in 2.1 but not 1.5.