# Android Button loses its Text Alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some buttons and a Spinner in my Layout. I Play Music on button click. When Button is pressed then button text gets aligned to left. I don't know why its happening. If I comment button click listener and then if I change items in Spinner , then also it gets Left Aligned.

Here is the part of my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCall"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="C" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCut"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="X" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is Activity Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    spnList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnList);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("First");
list.add("Second");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        BabyMobile1.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spnList.setAdapter(adapter);
spnList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    activeItem = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the code (Java and/or XML) you use to create your button and its listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining width and height attributes on your buttons. Try with adding below attributes.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Example:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCall"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="C" 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Edit:** Answer above gives a solution to keep texts of buttons center horizantal but their texts are shifted up when I tested. I searched this a while and found [similar problem (not answered yet) at stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995020/issue-with-button-text-shifting). I guess there is a small bug when using `Spinner`s(or dialogs) inside a `RelativeLayout`. I tried to change your layout below(changed root to `LinearLayout`) and it worked as expected. If you have a chance to replace your layout with mine(below) your problem will be solveld. But I have no idea why using `RelativeLayout` causes a problem like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCall"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="C" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCut"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="X" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I was using Style attribute for height and width. I removed it in this code. However it was not working while having height and width defined.

Comment: Have you tried to use layout on my answer? Main problem comes from Relative layout with Spinners I guess. Just copy mine and paste it to your main1.xml. Do you have the same problem then?

Comment: Thanks Aegean for doing research, I pasted your code and it worked as expected. You provided an alternate solution to use Linear Layout than using Relative Layout.
I was working on 2.2, Now I shifted my code by creating a new project on 4.3 and it worked. However when I created new project on 2.2 then it did not worked. I think new Version has resolved the bug which was in Relative Layout.

Comment: The solution for me involved hiding (set visibility to GONE) and then showing again (set visibility to VISIBLE) the button before and after an offending setText call. I've posted a new Q&A here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514288/buttons-text-gets-wrong-alignment-after-a-settext-call-on-a-textview

Answer (score 0):

Check the alignments of the button and spinner, if you are using Custom items in spinner then you should check the custom item alignment also.

better understanding purpose give me the code what u are writeing and where you are getting problem?

Answer (score 0):

check this link it may helps you.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android:gravity

here there is a tag in Spinner

```
android:gravity="   "
```

using this align the selected item in required position.

Comment: Nothing happens to Spinner. But if its selection is changed then button gets affected.